# What's the difference between report visuals and tiles in power bi embedded?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

It's not clear to me what the difference between power bi report visuals and tiles?  the report visuals has more interaction interfaces where as tiles do not.

Is it just a readonly report visual?

Also with the report visual, do you not have the capability to add context menu as well which is available with when you render the report?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the origin of the Power BI artifact and the setup required to retrieve it.

Report visual - as the name suggests, this is a visual that resides inside a Power BI report.
To embed it you'd need to use:

```js
 
// Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
// This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
// This also includes settings and options such as filters.
// You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
var config= {
    type: 'visual',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: txtAccessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: reportId,
    pageName: pageName,
    visualName: visualName
};
 
// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#visualContainer')[0];
 
// Embed the report and display it within the div container.
var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
```

Where `id` refers to the ReportId, `pageName` & `visualName` refer to the page it resides in and visual name respectively.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Single-Visual

Tile - this is a dashboard tile, that is essentially a visual that is **pinned to a dashboard** in Power BI.

```js
// Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
// This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
// You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
var config= {
    type: 'tile',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    id: embedTileId,
    dashboardId: embedDashboardId
};

// Get a reference to the embedded tile HTML element
var tileContainer = $('#tileContainer')[0];

// Embed the tile and display it within the div container.
var tile = powerbi.embed(tileContainer, config);
```

Where `id` is the tile id (GUID), and `dashboardId` is the dashboard it resides in.

**Edit**

Another difference, is that Report Visual supports all features that are available in Report Embed, e.g. bookmarks, export data, custom layout, menu extensions.. Whereas tile only supports dashboard interactions which currently are limited to various events, the main one being 'tileClicked' event

Comment: However, with power bi embedded you can't really pin a tile to a dashboard or remove a tile.  So effectively it's just used as a way to display the graph whether it's a tile or report visual.  So the question is what is really the difference if you can't pin or remove from the dashboard within the the scope of embedding it in a website.  The config is slightly different but the output is the same no?

Comment: Essentially, yes. the main difference is if you already have a dashboard you want to display selected tiles from.
Also, in some cases, tiles present a snapshot of the visuals configuration, whereas report visuals are affected by report & page level filters and other adjustments.